# Did Jeff Atwood convince Facebook to have employees answer FB questions?

Tags: discussion, facebook, jeff-atwood

Jeff [visited](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/92047188938596353) Facebook headquarters Friday. Now today two Facebook [partner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850494/jeff-sherlock) [engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850730/daniel-schultz) employees are answering Facebook related questions (I noticed they were FB employees because they put that in their signature of every question answered, see the edits).  Was this Jeff's doing? Or what was the purpose of the visit?

It is also interesting, considering Jeff is [anti-Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/stack-overflows-presence-on-facebook-could-be-a-bit-better/18644#18644)

Comment: Well .. Jeff _does_ love cats .. and sometimes cats accidentally bring strange things home with them.

Comment: `"Now today two Facebook partner engineer employees are answering Facebook related questions"` You say that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: @Anna Lear its not a bad thing at all considering you can rarely get a response from FB at all on their own site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We're in the process of actively reviewing all of our developer support channels, and exploring various channels of effective one-to-many support for our developer community. StackOverflow has always had a great reputation and around when Joel visited our developer support team decided to invest some time here. Please let me know if you think we can do anything to be more effective in our support.

Comment: just in case some of the feedback here seems ambiguous, I think I can safely say that you are very welcome here.

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't be surprised if this was just co-incidental. I remember watching a talk on Google Videos that Jeff (or was it Joel? Might have been Joel actually) did at Google about Stack Overflow and what they had learned. It wasn't meant to be a promotional tour, but it ended up getting a lot of Google staff onto the site.

Comment: Yes. Informing people about a site often results in them participating on that site. It doesn't mean the sole purpose of the discussion was to boost participation, it's just a logical outcome. Especially if the site is as high quality as this one.

Comment: “It wasn't meant to be a promotional tour” … you might not understand what promotion is …

Comment: @Konrad - the impression I got was that the purpose of the talk was to share the experience that Stack Exchange had with building a successful community. Not to promote SE.

Comment: @Farseeker Everything Joel does is for promotion. This doesn’t mean he’s a marketing whore, merely that *by its nature*, every time he shares his experience this creates exposure for SE. Best. marketing. *ever*.