# What is the best site to ask Facebook questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, facebook

I have some questions about managing a Facebook page, and I've done a search for Facebook related questions on Stack Exchange and can't really make a good determination of which Stack Exchange site to ask in. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of what a question might be?

Comment: Sure 1)Is there a way to change the default image in the photo tab? 2) Is there an email address for pages (like there is for users username@facebook.com)? 3)Is there a way to see (and export) the names of literally all of my page's fans? possibly through an app?

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @gobernador surely not for 1), probably not for 2) and quite certainly not for 3).

Comment: @Pekka yes, I agree. Unfortunately, asifahnik posted his comment instantaneously before I posted mine. My comment was purely facetious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Web Applications has a [Facebook tag with a thousand questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook).  The [Web Applications FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) suggests that such questions may be on topic there.

Answer (score 5):

Answer suggested by Charles is more specific and you will get solution there also.
For questions on *using* Facebook, ask on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

For *programming* questions about Facebook, you can ask on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ - this isn't really a *separate site*, merely a custom "view" of Stack Overflow with an emphasis on Facebook questions. Note that "programming" means "developing an app that connects with Facebook's APIs in some way". As with the rest of Stack Overflow, [the FAQ applies](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

There are above 29k questions on of [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook). Many facebook developers and facebook people are also watching out questions. More chances to get solved problem faster.
See

1. [Facebook.SO for all developer support, not just programming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103833/facebook-so-for-all-developer-support-not-just-programming)
2. [Was there an expectation that Facebook employees would help with their mini-site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104047/was-there-an-expectation-that-facebook-employees-would-help-with-their-mini-site)
3. [Did Jeff Atwood convince Facebook to have employees answer FB questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98961/did-jeff-atwood-convince-facebook-to-have-employees-answer-fb-questions)

For support questions, see: http://www.facebook.com/help/ - Stack Exchange does not and cannot provide answers about problems with your account, billing, etc.