# What would be the best Stack Exchange site to report problems or bugs concerning Facebook and social media technology in general?

Tags: support, facebook, authentication, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best site to ask Facebook questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136560/what-is-the-best-site-to-ask-facebook-questions)

Some background to the question: Facebook provides services to protect your account from being taken by someone else.

The result can be that if you forget your password, you go through a lengthy process to get access to your account again. Also, Facebook takes you through an account retrieval process when you try to access the Facebook services when you are (far) away from home
or use devices that are unknown to Facebook.

In some cases, people do not succeed to obtain access again. Either they are not using the system as designed or the system is not behaving as it should.

Please confirm if you have or you know someone that experienced problems while using the Facebook checkpoint system.

Comment: See [What is the best site to ask Facebook questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136560)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thank you however I would like a stackexchange site please

Comment: I am sorry if anyone thinks this is unconstructive or off topic. I However wouldnt it be usefull to ask people who consider themselves interested in improving social media applications what their experiences are with this specific functionality ?

Comment: You're fine.  It's neither unconstructive nor off-topic.  It's just been asked before =)  Also, if you're worried about the downvotes, [they are different here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  It doesn't necessarily reflect on the quality of your post.

Comment: @HCP: The accepted answer of [What is the best site to ask Facebook questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136560) points to [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), which **is** a SE site.

Comment: We are not Facebook.  Ask them.

Answer (score 12):

Well... none, I think. If you are having a problem logging into Facebook, nobody on SE can help you. You'll need to tell Facebook about your problem directly, and ask them for help.

SE isn't for reporting bugs in software or web sites,  it's about getting answers to your questions; and "I can't log in" is definitely not a question.

If, on the other hand, you would like to ask if *other* people have problems with the current checkpoint system, then I'm tempted to say the answer is still "none", because opinion and polling questions are explicitly off topic.

Comment: Thanks fr your comment, surely that would be the appropriate channel for help if you experience problems. But I would like to ask if people generally have problems with the current checkpoint system.

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, I'm tempted to say the answer is still "none", then, because opinion and polling questions are explicitly off topic.